# How can I force git to write error messages when calling it from another program

Tags: c#, git, process, tty

I am invoking git from a C# program using the `Process` class. When git fails on the command line, it writes useful error content to standard out. However, when invoked via `Process` it writes nothing to either standard out or standard errors on the same failure (e. g. trying to pull from a remote repo with no internet access). Presumably this is because git is detecting that it is not being run in a terminal window and therefore deciding not to write any messages. Is there a way to force this behavior so I can capture the messages?

Note: I'm aware of NGit but I don't want to use it because I've run into performance issues with using it on large repositories.

Comment: Start capturing the output; to start reading up on that, have a look here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @SineNomen I'm already doing that. Git isn't writing anything to stdout. I think this is because it only does so when stdout is a tty. I'd like to find a way to force the behavior

Comment: That seems more git related than C# related, maybe git manual(s) can tell you a bit more about piping the standard output/error to a specific destination?